# unzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: vs-code

When i run this command in VS Code terminal 
`unzip -o metadata/unpackaged.zip -d metadata` i get an error like this

```
unzip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 3):

`unzip` is not a normal Windows program. If you are using PowerShell or CMD as your shell, it typically won't work. If you want this feature, you'd need to install some version of Bash (e.g. [Git Bash](https://gitforwindows.org/)). From there, you can use the `unzip` command from a bash shell, or, if you select the appropriate installation options (UNIX tools in CMD), you can use `unzip` in CMD and PowerShell as well.

Comment: i'm using unzip command in the CLI in VS Code IDE how it can be work??

Comment: @sallyyamak VS Code only has access to whatever the OS does. You need to have unzip installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Expand-Archive` command instead of `unzip` command for unzipping.
[Expand-Archive Doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-7)